# How to pass device mappings and tag specifications to Boto3 Python run_instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to create an EC2 instance using the below code:

```
response = EC2.run_instances(
#    BlockDeviceMappings=deviceMappings,
    BlockDeviceMappings=[
{
    "DeviceName": "/dev/xvdb",
    "VirtualName": "swap",
    "Ebs": {
        "DeleteOnTermination": True,
        "Encrypted": True,
        "VolumeType": "standard",
        "VolumeSize": 16
    },
},
],
    ImageId=amiId,
    MaxCount=1,
    MinCount=1,
    InstanceType=instance_class,
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior='stop',
    SubnetId=subnet_id,
#    SecurityGroupIds=security_groups,
    SecurityGroupIds=['sg-8c2bb6f5','sg-edc49b89'],
#    TagSpecifications=tagSpecs
    TagSpecifications=[
    {
        'ResourceType':'instance',
        'Tags':[
            {
                'Key':'owner',
                'Value':'Sanjeev'
            },
            {
                'Key':'Name',
                'Value':'SanjeevTEST'
            },
            {
                'Key':'Environment',
                'Value':'PreProduction'
            },
        ]
    },
]
)
```

Code works as expected when BlockDeviceMappings, SecurityGroupIds and TagSpecifications are provided in line as above. But, when But, when I read them from a file into a variable and pass the variable, then the command fails with below error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter TagSpecifications, value: [
    {
        'ResourceType':'instance',
        'Tags':[
            {
                'Key':'owner',
                'Value':'Sanjeev'
            },
            {
                'Key':'Name',
                'Value':'SanjeevTEST'
            },
            {
                'Key':'Environment',
                'Value':'PreProduction'
            },
        ]
    },
]
, type: <type 'str'>, valid types: <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>
```

I am storing the device mappings, security groups and tags in a file as we have to create multiple instances and don't want to edit the code whenever we need to create a new instance.

How do I resolve this error? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your tags object is being treated as a **string** rather than as an object. Use this to convert the string into a Python dictionary:

```
TagSpecifications = json.loads(string_from_file)
```

See: [How to use JSON with Python](https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/python-xml-json/)

Comment: Thanks John, that fixed it.